Having problems with Ubuntu 24 update
So i recently updated my ubuntu version from 22 to 24. Ever since the update I have faced issues with my internet. It connects to some but doesnt connect to most of them. Although it would work on my other devices, it just refuses to work with my laptop. Additionally, I have faced issues like when I disconnect the HDMI from my second monitor, it just logs out my laptop whilist closing all the application (like when restarting). One of the USB-C ports which i could charge with does not output power anymore so I cannot charge my other devices again.
Can these be fixed?

Does this answer your question? Cannot upgrade from Ubuntu 23.10 or 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04
